# How to prevent a table from appearing

Tags: php

[Link to code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zrklu.png) Since you cannot divide by 0, my php is to display an error message but, although it displays the error message it also displays the table that should appear if not dividing by 0. How can I prevent that?

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
        <title>Math Calculations!</title>
        </head>
        <body>
        <!-- Background color selection for site-->
        <body style="background-color:#ACDDE3;">
        <?php
```

My values

```
        // input values
        $firstInt = $_POST["firstInt"];
        $secondInt = $_POST["secondInt"];
        $calc = $_POST["calc"];
        $result = 0;
        // inc-math-problems.php
        include ("juarez-inc-calc.php");
```

The statements

```
        elseif ($calc == "Multiplication") {
        $calculation = "Multiplication";
        $prefix = "The product of";
        $result = prodIntegers($firstInt, $secondInt);
        }
        elseif ($calc == "Divison") {
        $calculation = "Divison";
        $prefix = "The quotient of";
```

Target

```
        if ($secondInt == 0){
            print("Error: You can't divide by zero
            $result = "invalid";
        }
        else{
        $result = quotIntegers($firstInt, $secondInt);
        }
```

The print statements

```
        print("<style>
        table, th, td {
        border: 1px solid black;
        padding: 5px;
        }
        table {
        border-spacing: 5px;
        }
        </style>
        </head>
        <body>

        <h2>The Results</h2>

        <table>
        <tr>
        <th>Operation</th>
        <th>Result</th> 
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>$calculation</td>
        <td>$result</td>
        </tr>
        </table>");

        print("<a href=\"juarez-calculations.html\"> Return to form        </a>");

        ?>

        </body>
        </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if ($secondInt == 0){
    print("Error: You cannot divide by zero");
    $result = "invalid";
}
else{
    $result = quotIntegers($firstInt, $secondInt);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the your target block:-

```
if ((int)$secondInt === 0){
    print("Error: You can't divide by zero");
    $result = "invalid";
}
else{
    $result = quotIntegers($firstInt, $secondInt);
}
if($result!="invalid"){
//////print your table here
}
```

Comment: which type of functions? i need to see the all code then i can suggest somthing.

Comment: could you please show me this function prodIntegers($firstInt, $secondInt)

Comment: then i have no clear vision about you code. i have to see you code. could you if you wish?

Comment: could you echo $result before printing the table. then please tell me what are you getting in the case of division by zero.